# Using pyshp to create line shapefiles with color

Tags: python, shapefile, color, pyshp

I am using PyShp to create line shapefile in Python.

```py
w = shapefile.Writer('shapefiles/line')
w.field('name', 'C')
w.line([ [[3,2],[2,6]] ])
w.record('linestring1')
w.close()
```

Is there a way to specify a different color (and width) for each line object?

Comment: This question indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what a shapefile is. Shapefiles are GIS datasets. In the GIS model, unlike in the CAD model, data is data, and symbolization is a drawing rule, managed by a map project (often based on attributes). You can add attributes 'COLOR' and 'WIDTH` to the shapefile, and populate these values, and this will mean *nothing* to the majority of GIS packages until these attributes are explicitly linked to symbolization. In the end, it is not possible to create a shapefile with color, only to customize symbolization using GIS-specific tools.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the clarification. Can you explain a little bit more how to add attributes 'COLOR' and 'WIDTH' to the shapefile and populate these values and explicitly link these attributes to symbolization. That would really help. I would like to create isoline plot in ArcGIS. I know gdal can do this. Just wonder if there is a way to work this around with PyShp.

Comment: No, but you can [Edit] the question to ask this, and then maybe a pyshp user can help you. You should, of course, make an effort by reviewing the documentation first.